# Ionic 4 run browser failed to load resource

Tags: ionic-framework, browser, resources, ionic4

I created an easy Ionic 4 sidemenu app called "test" with `ionic start test sidemenu --type=angular`.

Then, without change anything, I run `ionic cordova run browser` and automatically it opens the browser and all works and is good.

The problem is if I try to open the `/platforms/browser/www/index.html` file directly in a browser, then I get a black page and the error `failed to load resources` for the files: `runtime.js, polyfills.js, styles.js, cordova.js, vendor.js, vendor.js`.

Same behavior if I run `ionic cordova run browser --prod`.

With ionic 3 I didn't have errors.

Failed to load resources:

[image]

My Ionic info is:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.2.1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.13
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.8.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 0.8.6
   @angular/cli                  : 6.2.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.0.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : browser 5.0.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.0, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/home/losciur/Android/Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v8.12.0 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Linux 4.8
```

Comment: Any breakthrough here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Add** `<base href="." />` in *index.html* and **remove** `<base href="/" />`.

Comment: I did so, but now icons are not loaded